# Database ComboBox component whose items are loaded from the database?

Tags: database, delphi, components

Is there a database component allowing for navigating through an attached dataset with a combobox look & feel? Upon setting the `DataSource`, a specifiable field would be 'loaded' into the `Items` property, and when the user selects an item, the dataset navigates to the selected record. Does such a component exist?

Comment: Guess, I haven't made myself clear - of course I know that.. Let me try it a different way: I am looking for dbnavigator functionality in a combobox-like component - does that clear it up?

Comment: I'm not aware of a DB-aware ComboBox that works quite the way you describe. Normally the items are fixed and selecting an item just updates the current record. For what you want, I would suggest using a standard `TComboBox` and handle the DB potion manually. Query the DB for the desired field and add the found items to the list. Then when an item is selected, query the DB for the desired record using the selected item.

Comment: That's what I have been doing so far. A few rather expensive component suites (such as Woll2Woll's InfoPower) have components that come close, but would be overkill in my case. It's a question that has been raised multiple times here over the years - just wondering if something had crept up lately ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `TDBLookupComboBox` omitting the `DataSource` and `DataField` property. You have to link the `ListSource` to your actual data source, the `KeyField` to the field used for the order and the `ListField` to the field(s) to be displayed.

Comment: Ah - a solution so close to home!

Comment: Hmm - yes, the data gets loaded, but navigation doesn't happen when I select an item. Furthermore, after loading, the current  item does not show as text...

Comment: Can you explain your expectations in more detail? I have no problem to achieve what you describe in your question. I connected a TDBGrid to the same DataSource as the combobox ListSource and each selection moves the current grid row to the selected record.

Comment: @UweRaabe he wants to navigate a database based on what's selected in the ComboBox.  Tua: you will need to use an event of the TDBLookupComboBox to navigate, such as TDBLookupComboBox.OnCloseUp, check the TDBLookupComboBox.KeyValue and use that value to navigate.

Comment: @JohnEasley, that is exactly what I get when doing what I proposed.

Comment: That does the trick! Wish I could give 2 votes!